# Rancher service links not working

Tags: rancher

In Rancher there is the option to specify service links but these do not seem to work when creating a link to a service running on another host machine.

In this particular case, the host machine's IP is `10.10.10.10`
and the container's ip is `10.20.0.1`. When resolving the link it says:

`PING link.rancher.internal 10.20.0.1 56(84) bytes of data`

The problem is, the client is trying to reach the container through the host machine, but the DNS resolves to the container itself, making it impossible to reach. It should either make `link` point to `10.10.10.10` or be able to reach `10.20.0.1` from the other containers.

Is there something that needs to be done to the networking config to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your configuration like docker-compose.yml, or the Rancher version, I could only assume that you could try the "external_links" directive in the case of linking two stacks together (see [adding-servcices](http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/v1.2/en/cattle/adding-services/))

For example, you have one database stack with the stack name "database", you could refer to the service names in other stacks like:

```
external_links:
- database/postgresql:db
```

Hope it works for you.